# Mysql_fetch_assoc() warning with my query using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

Getting this error `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` when I return my query

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempusers
    WHERE 'firstname' LIKE '%$data%' 
    OR 'lastname' LIKE '%$data%'
    OR 'description' LIKE '%$data%'
    OR 'title' LIKE '%$data%'");

if (! $query){
    echo'Database error: ' . mysql_error();
}
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $description = $row['description'];
    echo $description;
}
```

Specifically, the while loop. Not understanding why I'm getting. I'm thinking it's because of my use of LIKE, I am unsure if I am using the `wildcard's %%` correctly with my query. I would appreciate knowing how to rid of this error and why it happened

Comment: Remove the quotes surrounding the field names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use `CONCAT()` function
- use backtick instead of single quote on column names (*but in this case it is not required since your column name is not a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) or it does not contain invalid characters on it*)

query,

```
SELECT * FROM tempusers
WHERE  `firstname` LIKE CONCAT('%', '$data', '%')
    OR `lastname` LIKE CONCAT('%', '$data', '%')
    OR `description` LIKE CONCAT('%', '$data', '%')
    OR `title` LIKE CONCAT('%', '$data', '%')
```

one more thing, your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please take time to read the article below,

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: What would you recommend using @OlafDietsche?

Comment: @Octavius John's answer is fine, I have +1 it. I would have left the `like`s alone, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

```
why it happened?
```

For `SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN` and other statements returning resultset, `mysql_query()` returns a resource on success, or `FALSE` on error
Also for `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, the argument must be a proper resource not an object like `FALSE` in this case.

```
How to rid of this error?
```

Since the error is due to your query whose execution returns `FALSE`, this may be the solution to that.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tempusers`
        WHERE `firstname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
        OR `lastname` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
        OR `description` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'
        OR `title` LIKE '%" . $data . "%'");
```